# Узнать сколько времени осталось до удаления сессии

Tags: php, сессия

Пользователь авторизуется, сессия храниться 30 суток. Хорошо, при создании сессии, знаем время когда она обновиться.

Будет ли время сессии оттягиваться если пользователь, скажем зашел через 7 дней, будет ли время хранения увеличено на 7 дней?

И как узнать тайм удаления ссессии?

Comment: лайфтайм сессии прописан в конфиге пхп параметром session.gc_maxlifetime и по-умолчанию равен 24мин, работает в паре с параметром session.cookie_lifetime которым ты можешь продлевать лайфтайм сессии https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php

Comment: в скриптах доступны команды ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
session_set_cookie_params(0);